# C++ current system time in nanoseconds as long integer in order to send influxdb

Tags: c++, influxdb

I need to get system time in nanoseconds and send it to influxdb as a timestamp. I know

```
std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()
```

gives current system time in nanosecodns but I could not manage to convert it to primitive types.

When I pass the code below, I see something like 1970-01-09T... in the database

```
std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count()
```

Comment: Show the full code you have tried to convert with and explain what about that did not work.

Comment: If you're getting only 9 days since the UTC epoch, your database probably requires nanoseconds instead of milliseconds. If you upload milliseconds then it will result in a much shorter time.

Comment: Yes, this is not an issue with C++ so much as with needing to understand the internal representation of a date/time type in your database system.

Comment: @J.Schultke I understand but high_resolution_clock::now() return nanoseconds?

Comment: As an aside, I don't think there's any guarantee that the `time_point` associated with `std::high_resolution_clock` has a representation of nanoseconds.  You need to make use of [`std::chrono::duration_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/duration_cast).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `std::chrono::system_clock` instead of `high_resolution_clock`.  Only `system_clock` reliably measures time since the 1970 epoch (which is what influxdb will be expecting).

Secondly, `system_clock` isn't guaranteed to measure time in units of nanoseconds, but you can correct for that.

Here is how to get your platforms best estimate of the number of nanoseconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC (excluding leap seconds, which is normal and ok), and put it in a signed 64 bit integral type:

```
using namespace std::chrono;
long long t = time_point_cast<nanoseconds>(system_clock::now()).time_since_epoch().count();
```

Answer (score 1):

`now()` returns you a [time_point](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point). You need to convert it to a duration in order to get the number of nanoseconds.

Probably what you are looking for is the time since the epoch, so you can do something like

```
std::chrono::nanoseconds ns = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch();
unsigned long result = ns.count();
```

Comment: I tried this but then I always see 1970-01-09... in the database

Comment: @Scheff `unsigned long` is at least 32 bits but can be 64 bits. When compiling with MSVC it is 32 bits but on Linux with clang or GCC it's 64 bits. The best way of avoiding this fiasco is to use `uint64_t` or `uintmax_t`, or `std::chrono::nanoseconds::rep`.

Comment: @J.Schultke I'm fully aware of this fact. Hence, I considered `unsigned long result = ns.count();` as critical... Concerning `uint64_t`, I agree.

Comment: I used `unsigned long` as per OP question, but in the documentation you will see that `std::chrono::nanoseconds::rep` represents an 64bit or wider integer type.